# How do i exclude comments from ack results?

Tags: configuration, comments, ack

Hi im new to `ack` (actually started half an hour ago). Im impressed by the quality of the search results.

But in my source files there are a lot of comments and if i search for a class/function-name i get about 20 results with commented lines and 2 with the actual code.

Is there a way to exclude text after `//` and `#` or between `/* */`?

Comment: Do you find more informations about this now ?

Comment: Maybe [this thread on ack-users mailing list could interest you](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ack-users/sfNos0L7oOU)... But it says it's not possible, and explain why it won't.

Answer (score 4):

You could skip single line comments with something like this;

```
# ignore matches after //
ack '^[^//]*word'
# ignore matches after #
ack '^[^#]*word'
```

If you are using [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) instead, remember that it does multi-line matches:

```
# ignore matches after //
ag '^[^\n\r//]*word'
# ignore matches after #
ag '^[^\n\r#]*word'
```

Comment: Why is the `[^\r\n]` necessary? Doesn't ack only do single-line matches?

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right, edited. Ack returns single-line matches, but ag returns multi-line matches.

Comment: Also, `[^//]` won't do what you expect it too. You'd need a more complex matcher.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Instead, you tag your source.

Skipping comments would mean parsing the input on the fly, which is generally speaking slow. Moreover, each programming language has a different syntax for comments, which makes implementing this non-trivial. While you could roll your own regex -- e.g. for C use something like this: `\/\*(\*(?!\/)|[^*])*\*\/` -- these patterns are complex and more trouble than their worth for the quick searching that ack, ag, and grep are designed for. What you're really looking is a way to navigate your code via functions and classes; this is what tagging one's code is for: check out universal-ctags, http://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/.